# Troubleshoot Reliance transfer switch ACE side

Tags: generator, transfer-switch

When switched to LINE all circuits work. When switched to GEN, only circuits BDF work. ACE goes dead. I tested ACE with a volt meter and a clamp multimeter. Circuit A, for example draws 3A when on LINE. Switching to GEN drops it to 0.1- 0.2A.

BDF work great. Example, the 20A circuit it's drawing 11A from the generator during a test to run an air-conditioner. The other two 15A circuits draw 1.5 and 3A.

Generator is a 7000W Westinghouse.

I've double checked the wiring, and it is correct. The switch is new, and with the storm coming tomorrow, I'd love to have these other circuits running. I'm afraid I have a bad switch.[image]

I'm tempted to uninstall it and take it apart to test with a multi meter, but, I'd rather not.

Update: it looks like the bottom set of blades run the circuits in question. They are connected to a black wire on the side.

I was trying to see on the box looking for a lose connection, but, unfortunately, it's riveted, so access is limited at best.

[image: Updated image: inside of the box.]

Updated image: the box outside:

[image: box outside]

[image: Generator can generate either 120 or 240.]

Comment: Is the generator supplying both legs?

Comment: Yes. It supplies both sides (or should).

Comment: Added a picture so show the inside.

Comment: ACE are on the same pole.  BDF are on the same pole. The generator is not supplying pole ACE correctly. (Or it's broken in the switch).  Try switching poles as close to the switch as possible and see if the problem moves.

Comment: If generator is not supplying poles correctly, could that be a miswired outlet? I installed the outlet too, but have not checked that. I think human error on my part is more likely than being switch. (Also, going that is the real problem). I have to go outside to check that, will report back.

Comment: Also, is this a 240V generator?  Is it a new generator or has it successfully provided 240V before?

Comment: It successfully ran my other house before we moved into this house. I just serviced it.  I just checked the wiring outside. It's correct. Red to X, black to Y, ground to G, and neutral to W.

Comment: To answer your other question, it's a wh7000ec 120/240.

Comment: More information: according to the manual (above) the plug can provide either 120v or 240v. But, I cannot find a switch or anything in the manual that discusses how to check it. Tomorrow, once I have daylight, my next task to put a multimeter on the two hot wires and see if I get 240v and 120 between either hot wire and neutral. Unless you have another suggestion...

Comment: The red and black are opposite poles.  They are truly opposite, so **they are interchangeable**.  The only reason they make them different colors is cultural habit, and /3 Romex uses those colors from the factory.  When wiring 240V in conduit, I just use 2x the same color.  You can safely attach red-black and black-red in this case.

Comment: Update: I have confirmed the generator is providing 240 (actually 249v) by firing it up and putting a multimeter on the other directly. Dies this mean I have a bad transfer switch? I suppose I should connect to the outlet and measure at the transfer switch before it goes into the poles... To make sure the outlet and the wires are good...